# Streamlit rerunning script every time an action occurs

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a simple streamlit app. I wish to take 4 inputs from user and display the graph corresponding to those inputs..

```
import streamlit as st
name_option = st.selectbox("Select Name", ['A', 'B', 'C'])
gender_option = st.selectbox("Select Gender", ['M', 'F'])
date_option = st.selectbox("Select Date", predefined_date_list)
```

But Streamlit is rerunning a script every time an action occurs for example when I select name it reruns the script. Is there any way I can change this behaviour ? I would like to display the visualization based on the 4 selection (3 in pseudo example above)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a separate button for your app. When it's clicked the app generates the plot.

**Example:**

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

chart_data = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randn(5, 3),
        columns=["a", "b", "c"])


calculate_button = st.button('Calculate', on_click=None)

if calculate_button == True:
        st.bar_chart(chart_data)
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can also use SessionStates for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form

```
import streamlit as st

with st.form("my_form"):
  name_option = st.selectbox("Select Name", ['A', 'B', 'C'])
  gender_option = st.selectbox("Select Gender", ['M', 'F'])
  date_option = st.selectbox("Select Date", predefined_date_list)
  submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).